# How to fill background color of excel base on cell value with Python?

Tags: python, excel

1. I have a list of excel.

[image]

2. I use python to found duplicate record and update to excel.

   ```
   import openpyxl as xl
   import pandas as pd

   df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/User/Desktop/List.xlsx')
   df['Duplicate'] = df.duplicated(['Country', 'Name'], keep=False)
   upd_col_d = df['Duplicate']

   wb = xl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\List.xlsx')
   ws = wb.active

   for df_row, df_value in enumerate(upd_col_d, start=2):
   ws[f'D{df_row}'].value = df_value

   wb.save('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\List.xlsx')
   ```
3. The updated list

[image]

4. I want to use below function fill the row is yellow if column D value is TRUE but not work... Could tell me what is wrong with my function?

   ```
   import openpyxl as xl
   from openpyxl import Workbook
   from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
   from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule
   from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle 

   def background_colors(path):
       wb = xl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\List.xlsx')
       ws = wb.active
       yellow = "00FFFF00"
       for rows in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1, min_col=1, max_col=3):
            for cell in rows:
                if cell == 'TRUE':
                    cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color=yellow, end_color=yellow,
                                            fill_type="solid")
        workbook.save(path)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    background_colors('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\List.xlsx')
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few edits, but given the excel as was in the picture above, this code will read, update and save back the file with the rows marked as `TRUE` with yellow color.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, #Font, Border
#from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule
#from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle 

def background_colors(path):
    wb = xl.load_workbook(path)
    ws = wb.active
    yellow = "FFFF00"   #Correct HEX code for yellow
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=4):
        if str(ws.cell(row[0].row, 4).value).upper() == 'TRUE': #As true is reserved word, had to convert to string and then upper case
            for cell in row:
                cell.fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor=yellow)
    wb.save(path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    background_colors('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\List.xlsx')
```

**Output sheet**

[image]